# How to add background for responsive tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using this plugin: https://github.com/samsono/Easy-Responsive-Tabs-to-Accordion to create a vertical responsive tabs area. I wanted to add a background color for this area.
so I wrap that area with a div & give it a class named superdemo & add this css:

```
.super-demo{
        width:960px;
        margin: 200px auto 0;
        background: #FFF;
        padding:40px;
    }
```

this is my html:

```
<div class="super-demo">
        <!--vertical Tabs-->
        <div id="verticalTab">
            <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
                <li>Responsive Tab 1</li>
                <li>Responsive Tab 2</li>
                <li>Responsive Tab 3</li>
                <li>Long name Responsive Tab 4</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="resp-tabs-container">
                <div>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum nibh urna, euismod ut ornare non, volutpat vel tortor. Integer laoreet placerat suscipit. Sed sodales scelerisque commodo. Nam porta cursus lectus. Proin nunc erat, gravida a facilisis quis, ornare id lectus. Proin consectetur nibh quis urna gravida mollis.</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>This tab has icon in it.</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>Suspendisse blandit velit Integer laoreet placerat suscipit. Sed sodales scelerisque commodo. Nam porta cursus lectus. Proin nunc erat, gravida a facilisis quis, ornare id lectus. Proin consectetur nibh quis Integer laoreet placerat suscipit. Sed sodales scelerisque commodo. Nam porta cursus lectus. Proin nunc erat, gravida a facilisis quis, ornare id lectus. Proin consectetur nibh quis urna gravid urna gravid eget erat suscipit in malesuada odio venenatis.</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>d ut ornare non, volutpat vel tortor. Integer laoreet placerat suscipit. Sed sodales scelerisque commodo. Nam porta cursus lectus. Proin nunc erat, gravida a facilisis quis, ornare id lectus. Proin consectetur nibh quis urna gravida mollis.Suspendisse blandit velit eget erat suscipit in malesuada odio venenatis.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


</div>
```

but strangely it did not cover up the full area. yes I can set height for superdemo div, but I don't want to do it, so in future I can add as much as content possible & don't have to calculate the height again. here is the live link: http://banglapdf.net/testit/Index.html

what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
overflow:hidden;
```

to your wrapper css.. (.super-demo class)

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear content at the end.

```
<div class="super-demo">
    <div id="verticalTab">
        <!-- your content-->
        <div style="clear:both;"><!--clear content--></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: down voted because there is no need for extra div tags and that's why this is not good solution. Imagine if you would have to place this kind of divs in multiple places..